# Playing an array of sound files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass a variable into a JavaScript function and play it, using HTML5 `<audio>` element.

If I pass a string parameter into the function, this is only one file and I play that. But if I pass an array, I want to play the whole array, song by song.

Here is my basic idea:

```
function playSound(sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById('sound');
    if(sound instanceof Array) {
        // Play the whole array
    }
    else {
        // Play only one file
        audio.src = sound;
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to call `playSound` in a loop and bind the call to `onended`:

```
if (sound instanceof Array) {
    audio.src = sound.shift();
    audio.play;
    if (sound.length) {
        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            playSound(sound);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But if one of the sound file is missing and cannot be played, it plays after the next time I pass in a single file (the else in my example). Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: How can it ever play if it's missing?

Comment: Hehe, sorry. Let me explain better. `Action 1:` pass in array of files ['missing.mp3', 'second.mp3'] and it doesn't play anything because 'ended' event is never reached. Then in `Action 2:` pass in only one file (single.mp3), then it plays single.mp3 AND second.mp3

Comment: What I want is if the file is not found, it goes to the next. :)

Comment: Try also adding `addEventListener('ended error'`